# Solr Facet Pivot Date Field Gap

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search

How can I group the following solr query day by day, is it possible? I don't want re-index for date.

Solr Query

```
fq=feeddate:[2019-01-01T00:00:00Z%20TO%202019-02-01T00:00:00Z]
&facet.range={!tag=rdt}feeddate
&facet.range.start=2019-01-01T00:00:00Z
&facet.range.end=2019-02-01T00:00:00Z
&facet.sort=feeddate
&facet.range.gap=%2B1DAY
&facet=true
&facet.pivot=feeddate,sentiment
&q=*:*
&wt=json
```

Result

```
[ { field: "feeddate", value: "2019-01-01T00:00:10Z", count: 1, pivot: [ { field: "sentiment", value: 2, count: 1 } ] },
  { field: "feeddate", value: "2019-01-01T00:00:14Z", count: 2, pivot: [ { field: "sentiment", value: 2, count: 2 } ] },
  { field: "feeddate", value: "2019-01-01T00:00:15Z", count: 3, pivot: [ { field: "sentiment", value: 0, count: 2 }, { field: "sentiment", value: 2, count: 1 } ] },
  { field: "feeddate", value: "2019-01-01T00:00:16Z", count: 1, pivot: [ { field: "sentiment", value: 2, count: 1 } ] }
]
```

I want to get the total result by grouping the incoming result day by day

Comment: Interesting. May be try the json.facet instead of the facet.pivot. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/json-facet-api.html#range-facet-parameters

Comment: @WinnieDaPooh, I tried it and it didn't work. I think, facet pivot also facet range doesn't work.

Comment: What did you try and what did not work, please? Give specifics. Update the question with the json facet query that you tired. May be people can help.